# ¿Como configurar correctamente EntityManagerFactory de JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish

Hola actualmente me encuentro aprendiendo JavaEE por ende me encuentro en mi primera configuración a JPA, pero estoy presentando algunos errores, revisando mi código no logro esclarecer la excepción Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named PersonaPU, no logro entender como solucionarlo o si es error de librerías. Agradecería su guía y esclarecimiento de dichos fallos con glassfish:

```
WARNING: javax.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named PersonaPU
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
 at co.com.practice.test.ClienteEntidadPersona.main(ClienteEntidadPersona.java:11)
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
 at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
 at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
 at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:1000)
 at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:947)
 at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:471)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
 at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
 at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
 at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  2.445 s
Finished at: 2024-02-07T07:49:44-05:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec (default-cli) on project HolaMundoJPA: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Clase entidad:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Persona implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idPersona;
    
    @Column(name = "idpersona")
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String correo;
    private String telefono;

    public Persona() {
    }

    public Persona(String nombre, String apellido, String correo, String telefono) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.correo = correo;
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public int getIdPersona() {
        return idPersona;
    }

    public void setIdPersona(int idPersona) {
        this.idPersona = idPersona;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public String getCorreo() {
        return correo;
    }

    public void setCorreo(String correo) {
        this.correo = correo;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Persona{");
        sb.append("idPersona=").append(idPersona);
        sb.append(", nombre=").append(nombre);
        sb.append(", apellido=").append(apellido);
        sb.append(", correo=").append(correo);
        sb.append(", telefono=").append(telefono);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
}
```

archivo persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd" 
             version="2.2">
    <persistence-unit name="PersonaPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>co.com.practice.domain.Persona</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=fals&amp;useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.loggin.parameters" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Clase ClienteEntidadPersona en la cual estoy lanzando la persitencia:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import co.com.practice.domain.Persona;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.*;

public class ClienteEntidadPersona {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersonaPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        
        //Inicia la transaccion
        tx.begin();
        //No se debe especificar el ID de la base de datos
        Persona persona1 = new Persona("Maria","Gutierrez","mgutierrez@mail.com","88991199");
        log.debug("Objeto a persistir:" + persona1);
        //Persistimos el objeto
        em.persist(persona1);
        //terminamos la transaccion
        tx.commit();
        log.debug("Objeto persistido" + persona1);
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Adicional anexo la estructura de archivos que estoy usando mediante Netbeans
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a los aportes datos, identifique lo siguiente en la configuración del archivo pom.xml para glassfish maven, se debe agregar la siguiente dependencia:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.15.Final</version><!--Ideal versiones finales para evitar conflictos-->
        </dependency>
```

finalmente en el archivo de persistencias persistence.xml debe contar con la siguiente configuración:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd" 
             version="2.2">
    <persistence-unit name="PersonaPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider><!--org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence seencuentra deprecado-->
        <class>co.com.practice.domain.Persona</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false&amp;useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/> <!-- Para mostrar las consultas SQL generadas por Hibernate -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

y por último pero no menos importante un pequeño detalle y a modo de corrección, la configuración de la clase entidad la cual permitirá el manejo de la información hacia la base de datos debe contar con la instrucción @Column(name ="nombre_id")  antes de definir el atributo id, ejemplo:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idpersona")
    private int idPersona;
```